# gcloud scp not working inside Google functions

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I have a google function which is trying to copy a shell script to one of the instances. It works fine in a normal python file but on google functions it throws the below error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gcloud': 'gcloud'
```

**Sample Code**

```
command = "gcloud compute scp --project " + "robotic-century-2524902" + " " + "/tmp/test.sh" + " " + "instance-12" + ":~/" + \
                      " " + "--zone " + "us-central1-a"

status = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(command))
```

I have the below packages `google-cloud==0.34.0,gcloud==0.18.3` added as well to requirements.txt.
Any help here??

Comment: Do not confuse Cloud Functions with an operating system. There are no commands inside Cloud Functions. You write the code. Cloud Functions runs that code. If you want a feature, you write that feature.

Answer (score 4):

Google's use of `gcloud` formally Cloud SDK is confusing.

[`google-cloud`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-cloud) and [`gcloud`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcloud) (deprecated) do not provide a command-line akin to the `gcloud` command that you're familiar with and which provides e.g. `gcloud compute scp...`

These NPM packages are, in fact, SDKs for various Google Cloud Platform API's underlying the command-line gcloud.

When you run `gcloud ...` on the command-line, the `gcloud` binary makes API calls to the Google Cloud Platform services and the NPM packages that you reference provide JavaScript|Node.JS SDKs for these APIs. You may see which APIs are being invoked by `gcloud` commands by appending `--log-http` on any command.

In this case, there's another wrinkle because `gcloud` is actually using your host's installed scp command beneath-the-covers; `gcloud compute scp...` is a convenience wrapper for `scp` that also manages the ssh auth for you.

It is not possible (because the `gcloud` command-line is [probably] not installed on the Cloud Functions instance) and it is not advisable to execute shell commands from within Cloud Functions.

When you run your code locally, it is running under your user credentials (`gcloud config get-value account`) and this user has permission to ssh/scp to the instance thanks to gcloud's work provisioning keys for the user on the instance.

Running as a Cloud Function, you'd probably want to give the Cloud Function permission to act as the Compute Engine instance's service account. This could become messy|complicated.

An alternative may be to dump the script into Google Cloud Storage (GCS) from the Cloud Function and then have the Compute Engine instance reference|collect it from GCS.

Could you provide more detail on what you're trying to do? I understand the Function wants to dump a script on the instance. But, how is the Function acquiring the script and what does the script do?

Comment: My use case is just to copy .sh file (which has some packages to be downloaded) to each instance and then ssh and ./myscript.sh on each of those instances. It would get more complicated if i read the bucket from instances